# Chat room for religious discussions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

Is it OK to have a religious discussion chatroom on stackexchange? Which of the stackexchange sites should I use to create such a room?

I'd also like to be able to invite others to chat there somehow - will such a room support inviting users from other sites?

The idea being I would like some users to switch over to religious at times whenever I am in discussion with them on the programming stackexchange sites. Not likely to "drive" the crowd, but still.

**Edit:**

## Idea and Intention

I don't know why my intentions are questioned and scrutinized this way.Especially,when i am personally against such sort of spamming which is evident through my comments.There are rooms which are meant to discuss cheese and you are into them talking cheese but when you need to discuss bread you simply discuss it in another room meant for bread,else your chats are actually placed in the recycle bin.So i here i am,both in rooms of bread and cheese wanting to *invite a user* from cheese to bread (being clear that we both want bread now).

I don't know why this simple thing is being blown out of proportions.

## What i DON'T intend

I don't in any case support that sort of spamming which i am warned against in this post.On the contrary,I find people suggesting **spamming** in their answers while i propose **inviting** them.

[doppelgreener said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211069/213638):

> Find a site appropriate to the kind of discussion you want to have,
> and start a chat room there. ***Then copy the URL of that chat room and
> paste it into any other chat room*** to link it to people in there and
> invite them in.

I think this is what is called PROPER SPAMMING.I don't know how people warn against it and propose the opposite.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal? Check out http://chat.stackexchange.com/ - there are a few there. You'd have to be more specific - there are lots of religions, I doubt there's a generic chat room for all of them, if that's what you want.

Comment: i am more interested in knowing whether i can invite users from http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ to a room created in islam.stackexchange.. or should i tag that as a feature request?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood that - As I understand it, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ is for programming-related discussion. So you should be creating a room under http://chat.stackexchange.com/, not http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ (if there isn't already a similar one). Can you even invite users to some chat?

Comment: sorry nezam .. but why do you wish to such things on prograaming site .. do i need to write `IF` or `WHILE` loop depending on from which race or religion i come from??

Comment: @Nezam You're _saying_ you're asking if you can have a chat room somewhere on the Stack Exchange network, but your first sentence is asking whether someone can have one on _Stack Overflow_ - a programming site. You might want to edit that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the word 'invite'. That sounds dangerously close to 'spam all the chatrooms wanting people to come and chat about religion'. I would imagine that if people wanted to chat about religion then they'd just go to the chat rooms on their own accord. Popping up in various chat rooms around StackExchange spamming a religious chat site would likely annoy many people. (Just as if I were to do the same thing but invite people to come and chat about LEGO in my Lego chatroom - if people aren't interested (which most people aren't) then it's going to be annoying).

Comment: If someone starts talking religion on a programming chat room, then, by all means, tell them what they're saying is off topic and point them to a more appropriate room. If no-one's talking religion, you have no business mentioning anything about a religion chat room nor do you have any business just inviting people out of the blue, if that's possible. You perhaps need to be more explicit about how you're planning to invite people.

Comment: @Dhaval no you got it all wrong.People generally and often discuss non tech in chatrooms,in these cases they tend to discuss/share something which eases them off a bit from their work pressure.I like to discuss something fruitful in this case.So i would invite them over.

Comment: @JonW refer to my comment on Dhaval above to get what i mean

Comment: i believe that edit should revert the downvotes.

Comment: @Nezam Give us **a real example** of when you'd like to invite a user from http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ to a religious chat room. Either we'd tell you it's not appropriate or you may convince us that you're not trying to do something we don't approve of.

Comment: @Dukeling at first i would like to know what standard you are judging things? is politely inviting someone over to a discussion (which doesnt belong to the current room) is "not appropriate".. why is it then appropriate for a person to invite any cross stack exchange site?

Comment: @Nezam There are 100s of chat rooms, and I certainly don't want unsolicited invitations to most / any of them. If I'm interested in chatting about a topic, I'll go look for a room about it. Admittedly this process isn't perfect - if I go looking for a room and don't find one, I probably won't go looking again too soon, and I probably won't know if a new room on the topic is created, but I'm willing to deal with that if it means not hearing about all the other rooms I'm not interested in (and there are way better ways of dealing with this problem). So, do you have an example you can give us?

Comment: @Nezam the key point I think you're missing is: if a conversation is alerady happening and you want to suggest another venue, that's fine.  But if you want to start something that off-topic, personal, and controversial by randomly soliciting people, that's not ok.  And that's not how *dawah* works anyway, I'm told.  If you search chat.SE (not chat.SO) you'll find religion-related rooms where you can go and chat with like-minded folks; no problem there.  But proselytizing, or anything that looks like it, is likely to get you in trouble.

Comment: Read my edit all of you..

Comment: But Programming and religion are nothing like cheese and bread. As was requested previously - can you make one real world example where you would want to use this?

Comment: Thats a very biased and partial notion.

Comment: @Nezam Linking the chat is perfectly ok (it's one of the main ways to even invite people to rooms: link it, ask them if they want to move their discussion there). The circumstances under which you link it determine whether you're spamming or being constructive. There's no contradiction there. People were rightfully concerned about your circumstances under which you'd do this. It sounded like you'd just link it to people whenever, in order to advertise the room's existence: or in your terms, it sounded like you'd tell them about the bread room when they're discussing cheese, not bread.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can have a religious discussion room. Heck, we have several sites in our [Culture category](//stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) about religion:

- [Christianity](//christianity.stackexchange.com/)
- [Islam](//islam.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mi Yodeya](//judaism.stackexchange.com/)
- [Hinduism](//hinduism.stackexchange.com/)
- [Buddhism](//buddhism.stackexchange.com/)

(If you're after something else, [run a search on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/): if there's a proposal, consider joining it! If there isn't, consider creating it.)

Find a site appropriate to the kind of discussion you want to have, and start a chat room there. Then copy the URL of that chat room and paste it into any other chat room to link it to people in there and invite them in.

Comment: is there any site related to Hinduisam ??

Comment: @Dhaval There's a proposal for it, which I've linked.

Comment: @Dhaval check revised answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are separate chat systems for Stack Overflow and the rest of the Stack Exchange network. You can invite a user from any Stack Exchange site to any other SE site's chat, *except* for Stack Overflow which is separate.

There are already numerous religious chat rooms (generally for specific religious sites); they're not really treated any differently than any other chat room. You can invite anybody with a Stack Exchange chat account to them if you like, but make sure the invitation is appropriate and relevant to the conversation you're already having.